# What causes circuit breaker finders to not work properly?

Tags: electrical

Sperry circuit breaker finder, aprox 15 years old, It did work OK a few years ago.
I plug in the transmitter and the LED lights up. Then I go to the breaker panel and find a weak signal put can't narrow it down to one breaker. I find that where I get the signal is not even close to the proper CB. I suspect that maybe other electronics (cordless phones, computer, etc) that are on in the house are interfering w/the circuit breaker finder's electronics.

Comment: Have you tried turning off some of the electronic devices that you suspect are interfering? Have you taken the finder to another house to see if it works there? (they'll likely have a different electrical environment than you do, so failure in 2 places is likely equipment failure, while failure in one location only is likely environmental.)

Comment: Try turning the breakers off.  When you turn the right breaker off, the signal will go away altogether :)